# Validate DateTime in Validation Application Block

Tags: .net, validation, enterprise-library

How to validate DateTime by Validation Application Block, to not be more than DateTime.Now?

thanks.

Comment: I want to use the validator for the DateOfBirth field.so i don't want to accept the date that is greater than the system date. How can i check that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for validation just choose time format http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=504

Comment: The question is about Validation Application Block that is part of Enterprise Library.

Comment: @Vadim i see but it more easier with regex

Comment: the question is not about the format...it's about having a DateTime value less than or equal to another DateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this using the Validation Application Block would be to create a property that returns DateTime.Now and then use a Property Comparison Validator.

SelfValidation would also let you do what you want.  The Property Comparison Validator lets you externalize the logic but it feels a bit wrong to expose a property just to compare against.

**Implementation**

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

```
<type assemblyName="MyApp.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="MyApp.Entities.Person">   
  <ruleset name="MyRuleSet">
    <properties>
      <property name="BirthDate">
        <validator operator="LessThanEqual" propertyToCompare="Now" negated="false"
          messageTemplate="I don't know nothin' about birthin' no babies in the future." messageTemplateResourceName=""
          messageTemplateResourceType="" tag="" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.PropertyComparisonValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
          name="Property Comparison Validator" />
      </property>
    </properties>   
  </ruleset> 
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RelativeDateTimeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649529.aspx). The below assumes that we do not have people older than 140 years ([worlds oldest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people#Oldest_people_ever), so far, was 122 at time of death).

```
[RelativeDateTimeValidator(-140, DateTimeUnit.Years, 0, DateTimeUnit.Second,
       MessageTemplate = "Sorry, no predicted births allowed.")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{ get; set;}
```